# Как работает Abstract Factory в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, шаблоны-проектирования

Хотелось бы понять как конкретно работает эта абстрактная фабрика в Kotlin'e.В целом о каждом компоненте например (абстрактный клсасс,inline есть).Просто не могу понять как поэтапно проходит процесс создания нужной фабрики.Если бы вы могли помочь с этим уточнением в моей голове был бы признателен.

```
abstract class ChatFactory {
   abstract fun getChat(): Chat

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Chat> create(): ChatFactory =
        when (T::class) {
            FakeChat::class -> FakeChatFactory()
            SDKChat::class  -> SDKChatFactory()
            else            -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}

ChatFactory.create<FakeChat>().getChat().getChannels()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Клиентский код вызывает метод create() объекта-компаньона класса ChatFactory.
2. При вызове метода в type argument передается класс, реализующий Chat.
3. Внутри метода create() на основании фактического типа переданного класса создается соответствующая фабрика или выбрасывается исключение, если переданный класс не FakeChat либо SDKChat.

Comment: Не подскажите зачем здесь используется inline ?

Comment: inline необходимое условие для того, чтобы использовать reified. Модификатор reified позволяет получить доступ к информации о фактическом типе аргумента Т. Иными словами, без этих двух модификаторов не было бы возможности в теле функции написать T::class. Это связано с механизмом реализации generic-ов в Java, и как следствие в котлине. Чуть подробнее можете прочитать https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/inline-functions.html в разделе параметры вещественного типа